# Firefor Selenium IDE not recording certain websites

Tags: firefox, selenium, ide

Im new to automated testing and im trying to record a particualr scenario using firefox selenium IDE (Fireforx version : 26 ans selenium IDE version : 2.5). A couple of days I was able to record and play that scenario. But when I try doing the same today, it does not record anything and all i see is a plain window (no commands). But google, wikipedia, gmail everything gets recorded fine. There are no changes to the application and it is the same. (imacros are able to record). I have tried reinstalling firefox, selenium IDE and even restarted my machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Durga